# Restoring default toolbar layout in Blender 2.81

Tags: interface

I'm using Blender 2.81, when I open old Blender files such as Blender 2.80 or older the toolbar layout in the 3D Viewport are different than the default toolbar layout when starting a new project.

This is what it looks like when I open an old Blender 2.80 file

[image]

And this is what it looks like when I start a new Blender 2.81 project

[image]

And if I open projects from Blender 2.79 or older the toolbar appears on the bottom of the 3D viewport (which is even more annoying). Is it possible to reset all the layouts to the default 2.81 layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the file dialog**

When you are in the Open File dialog, click the *Settings* icon in the top right.

Then **deselect** *Load UI*

[image: File Dialog]

**Setting default behaviour**

You can also change the default behaviour by changing your preferences.

Go to *Edit → Preferences → Save & Load* and **uncheck** *Load UI*

[image: Preferences -> Save & Load]

Be warned that this might be equally frustrating if your startup file does not contain all the views you would expect.

Comment: Should like to add this is done by starting a new Blender file (now the interface is set to default) then choose File > Open to get to the Open File dialog (as in the answer above). The 'Load UI' can also be found under Preferences > Save & Load, but probably better to leave this checked to preserve the window and viewport layouts on a per-project basis. (For example if visualizing normals in one project leaving Load UI unchecked loses the overlay)

Comment: I've added it to the answer